# How can i make slider animation?

Tags: css, reactjs, accordion, react-bootstrap

I need to make the vertical slider animation ( `dots and line` ) as in this pic
[image]

i managed to do the Accordion and the dots but i don't know how i will going to implement it ( i'm using pseudo  )
[image]

**my accordion component Where i define the logic of my nested accordions as in images based on array of data **

```js
function MultiLevelAccordion({
  data,
  bodyClass,
  headerClass,
  wrapperClass,
  renderHeader,
  renderContent,
}) {
  const RootAccordionId = 'parent-0';
  const [accordionsStates, setActiveCardsIndex] = useMergeState({});

  const onAccordionToggled = (id, activeEventKey) => {
    console.log(activeEventKey);
    setActiveCardsIndex({
      [id]: activeEventKey ? Number(activeEventKey) : activeEventKey
    });
  };
  
  console.log('data', data);
  const accordionGenerator = (data, parentId) => { 
    return map(data, (item, index) => {
      const active = accordionsStates[parentId] === index;
      const hasChildren = item.hasOwnProperty('children') && isArray(item.children) && !isEmpty(item.children);
      const isRootAccordion = RootAccordionId === parentId;
      const isLastNestedAccordion = !isRootAccordion && !hasChildren;

      const accordion = (
        <Card className={classNames(wrapperClass, {
          'nested-root-accordion': !isRootAccordion,
          'last-nested-root-accordion': isLastNestedAccordion,
          'multi-level-accordion': !isLastNestedAccordion
        })}
        >
          <Accordion.Toggle
            {...{ ...item.id && { id: item.id } }}
            onClick={() => this}
            as={Card.Header}
            eventKey={`${index}`}
            className={'cursor-pointer d-flex flex-column justify-content-center'}
          >
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              {renderHeader(item, hasChildren)}

              <img
                style={{
                  transition: 'all .5s ease-in-out',
                  transform: `rotate(${active ? 180 : 0}deg)`
                }}
                src={setIcon('arrow-down')}
                className="ml-2"
                alt="collapse"
              />
            </div>
          </Accordion.Toggle>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={`${index}`}>
            <Card.Body
              className={`accordion-content-wrapper ${!hasChildren ? 'accordion-children-body' : ''} ${bodyClass}`}
            >
              {!hasChildren ? renderContent(item, hasChildren) : (
                <Accordion onSelect={activeEventKey => onAccordionToggled(`${parentId}-${index}`, activeEventKey)}>
                  <Fade cascade top when={active}>
                    {accordionGenerator(item.children, `${parentId}-${index}`)}
                  </Fade>
                </Accordion>
              )}
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse> 
        </Card>
      );

      return isRootAccordion ? accordion : (
        <div className={'d-flex align-items-center'}>
          {accordion}
          <div className="accordion-indicator-wrapper">
            <div className="accordion-indicator" id={`indicator-${parentId}-${index}`} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  if (!isArray(data)) {
    return;
  }

  return (
    <Accordion onSelect={activeEventKey => onAccordionToggled(RootAccordionId, activeEventKey)}>
      {accordionGenerator(data, RootAccordionId)}
    </Accordion>
  );
}


export default MultiLevelAccordion;
```

**the styles used in scss**

```css
.faqs-questions-wrapper {
  padding: 20px 10px
}

.faqs-q-count {
  color: $black-color;
  font-size: calc(1rem - 1rem/8)
}

.faqs-q-a-wrapper {
  flex-basis: 95%;
}

.faq-child-title {
  color: $black-color
}

.nested-root-accordion {
  flex-basis: 90%;
}

.accordion-indicator-wrapper {
  flex-basis: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  .accordion-indicator {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: $theme-color;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

Any clue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you got any code of what you currently have and I'll copy it to a pen. You could add a pseudo-element in between the dots and when you click the dropdown animate the hight of the pseudo

Comment: You will get many examples on the search engine. what is the issue you are facing in the code where you need the help is supposed to be asked here.

Comment: @CIB I provided the code could u please explain what's ur idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React JS is gonna make this easy

The lines expansion will need to be coded based on the height of the box window

For the dropdown container keep the vertical button lines in a separate div than the Accordian

Check out this pen for creating lines between buttons
https://codepen.io/cataldie/pen/ExVGjya
css part:

```
.status-container{
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.bullet{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 10;
}
.bullet:before {
  content: ' \25CF';
  font-size: 5em;
}
.bullet-before{
  /*position:relative;
  right:-12px;*/
}
.bullet-after{
  /*position:relative;
  left:-30px;*/
}
.line{
  stroke:blue;
  stroke-width:0.3em;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.line-on{
  stroke:red;
}
.line-off{
  stroke:gray;
}
.color-on{
  color: red;
}
.color-off{
  color: gray;
}
```

https://codepen.io/emwing/pen/LgzJOx

I think you can use some inspiration here